# CSV import skip duplicated records

Tags: django, csv

I'm using [django-adaptors](http://django-adaptors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)  I need a way to check for duplicated mobile numbers and skip the import of just these records while continuing to add the rest in the CSV file.

This is my current `CsvModel.py`

```
class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel):

    first_name = CharField()
    last_name = CharField()
    company = CharField()
    mobile = CharField()
    # groups = DjangoModelField(Groups)

    class Meta:
        delimiter = "^"
        dbModel = Contacts
```

this is the import

```
  # Try to import CSV
            ContactCSVModel.import_from_file(self.filepath)
```

Comment: Please show the code you wrote that attempts to do this and is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about using 3rd party apps for something this simple. just write a management command (name it myapp/management/commands/csvimport.py):

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from fabric.colors import _wrap_with
from optparse import make_option
import os, csv


green_bg = _wrap_with('42')
red_bg = _wrap_with('41')

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Command to import a list of stuff"
    option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option(
            "-f", 
            "--file", 
            dest = "filename",
            help = "specify import file", 
            metavar = "FILE"
        ),
    )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # make sure file option is present
        if options['filename'] == None :
            raise CommandError("Option `--file=...` must be specified.")

        # make sure file path resolves
        if not os.path.isfile(options['filename']) :
            raise CommandError("File does not exist at the specified path.")

        # print file
        print green_bg("Path: `%s`" % options['filename'])

        # open the file
        with open(options['filename']) as csv_file:
            reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            for row in reader:

                try :
                    object, created = Contacts.objects.get_or_create(
                        mobile = row[3],
                        defaults={
                            "first_name": row[0],
                            "last_name": row[1],
                           "company": row[2],
                        }
                    )
                except:
                    print red_bg("Contacts `%s` could not be created." % row['mobile'])
```

running this is real easy too:

```
python manage.py csvimport --file=path/to/myfile.csv
```

where csvimport is the filename of your management command.

Comment: `Contacts.objects.get_or_create` gets the record from the DB matching mobile OR creates a new record using the defaults dictionary https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is update in the meta options take this example...

```
class Meta:
        delimiter = ','
        dbModel = Product
        update = {
            'keys': ['name']   # or mfr_code, main_photo_url, etc..., price
        }
```

Will do the trick.